# django-rest-framework testing when view classes are permission protected

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-testing

In Django-Rest-Framework when a view class is permission protected by using

```
permissions_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

what is the best way to test it. I have django-rest-swagger but in-order to test the functionality I need to change the code to following to test

```
permissions_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

I'd love to figure out a way to pass in user token from swagger UI. I am curious to know other testing strategies as well.

Comment: This depends on what kind of authentication you're using, for example JWT uses a Authorization header which accepts a jwt token. I'm not 100% about swagger but for example postman can mock this header for testing authenticated endpoints. Using only sessionauthentication I'm not sure how you would fake that

Answer (score 0):

In Django Rest Framework, there are a lot of authentication scheme, so depending on the one you choosed, your test strategy will change.

Authorization header is ok if you're using TokenAuthentication for instance.

But if you're using SessionAuthentication, you should use django auth cookies.

I don't know JWT but with django-webtest, this would be easy to do.

With django-rest-swagger, if your permission_classes is [permissions.IsAuthenticated], then you can just log in Django (to set auth cookies) before using django-rest-swagger

Comment: with JWT a token is sent via header. It is not persisted in a cookie. Hence, I am unable to login to the application and then use the same browser to bring up swagger.

Comment: try (temporarily) to enable SessionAuthentication in your DRF config to see if it helps (and log in your Django account)

Comment: front end is Angular based and that only takes JWT. We won't be login to the system even if we changed backend to session based.